# I have two forms and i want to carry the data from first form to second form with the next button

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

i have 2 forms in React JS and i want to carry the data of the first form to the second form by clicking the next button .After that i want to check if the data is true then load the data of another form. If yes click the save button (Submit button) to save the data of the first and second form at same time onSubmit

Answer (score 0):

Save the data from the first form into [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html), then pass the state as [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) into the second form component. You can check if the data exists when the second component mounts with 'componentDidMount' or the useEffect Hook.

See this [article](https://css-tricks.com/the-magic-of-react-based-multi-step-forms/) on building multi-step forms with React.